# Writing a data frame into a .db format in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R called `df` and I would like to save it as a database file with a `.db` extension. I wonder if there is any way to do this in R?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look [here](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/RMySQL/html/RMySQL-package.html) for a package which can interface with MySQL and read tables into data frames (and presumably vice versa).

Comment: This seems to directly export to the database. As I don't have MySQL on my machine I'm looking for a way to save it as a database file and then open it on another machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `RSQLite` package, and `DBI`. Here's the modified example from [the vignette](https://github.com/rstats-db/RSQLite/blob/master/vignettes/RSQLite.Rmd):

```
library(DBI)

mydb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "mydb.db")
dbWriteTable(mydb, "mtcars", mtcars)
dbWriteTable(mydb, "iris", iris)
dbListTables(mydb)
```